# Is `continuation-local-storage` safe to use in production

Tags: node.js

We have done some experiments with the [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage), and it seems to solve a specific problem nicely.

What makes me nervous is that it relies on a polyfill of `process.addAsyncListener` that seems to have been deprecated ages ago.

This makes me worry a bit about using it for production code, so is it safe to use?

Our particular code base still has to run on node 6 on some servers for some time yet (it runs on node 8 on most servers).

**The problem**

This module helps us creating an execution context that is kept during async operations.

What we specifically add to this context are [bunyan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan) child loggers, initialized with context data, such as request ID/message ID/correlation ID.

This helps us to avoid having to pass tramp data through the layers, yet still being able to track all log messages associated with a specific request.

Comment: Why a downvote? If this is a poor question, I'd really like to know why, and how to improve it.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted but the question doesn't seem to be constructive. How can it be unsafe? Since there's no process.addAsyncListener, there's nothing to worry about. There's always a possibility that `process.addAsyncListener` global will be used for something else, but I guess it is pretty much low. But that's just guess. Generally, it's a bad practice to use non-compliant globals for solving local tasks, so it may be not a good idea to rely on a package that does that, especially if you didn't even start to use it. There may be better alternatives but I'm not aware of them.